# View image has data type Varbinary in datagridview from Database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

```
DataClasses1DataContext dbMenu = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        var query = from s in dbMenu.Menus where s.Dish_ID == DishID select s;
        var pic = from s in dbMenu.Menus where s.Dish_ID == DishID select s.photo;
        table.Columns.Add("Dish_ID", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Dish_Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Dish_Status", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Photo", typeof(string));

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
            dr["Dish_ID"] = item.Dish_ID;
            dr["Dish_Name"] = item.Dish_Name;
            dr["Price"] = item.Price;
            dr["Dish_Status"] = item.Dish_Status;
            dr["Photo"] = item.photo;
            table.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return table;
```

I tried like this but it didn't show images, it showed somethings that I don't really know.

[image: datagridview]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: As search for "aspnet display binary data as image" yielded [this promising result](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Binary-Image-from-database-in-ASPNet-GridView-control-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx).  The key piece of code is `string imageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])dr["Data"]);`, which appears to embed the image binary data into the image element URL as part of the RowDataBound event handler.  Note that this assumes that the binary data is a JPEG image. If you are using a different web architecture, you may still be able to adapt the same technique.